# Is there an issue with http://cdn.sstatic.net hosted images today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, cdn

I noticed images weren't loading properly from that domain and when i checked the img url directly I see:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/hosted/tKsDb.png

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: Looks fine from here. Could a proxy be in the way?

Comment: I get the same error message from Italy.

Comment: hmm, I get that too from CA.

Comment: In Firefox (where I am logged in) it's fine, but in IE/Chrome (where I'm not) I get a 401.

Answer (score 1):

We have moved these images over to imgur while we are in Oregon.  The new urls should be working at:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the links bar (eg: review, chat, main, faq) not being bold anymore?

Comment: Nope that change was intentional

Comment: **NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!**

Comment: So *that's* what is different about the links bar... my brain kept saying something was wrong with it, but I couldn't put my finger on the problem.