# Who stole the fox?

Tags: support, sponsored-tags

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox), the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) tag page:

> [image]

As far as I know this is Firefox official logo: ([original](http://blog.seanmartell.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo_0007_73.png))

[image]

I'm pretty sure it *used* to be that official logo until recently but now it's suddenly changed to blue and toothless theme of Mozilla foundation. ([This](http://blog.seanmartell.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo_0014_80.png) appears to be the original)

I wouldn't really mind unless discovering another oddity: that new logo is [hosted on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewopr.png), while all other sponsored tag icons I encountered are hosted on http://cdn.sstatic.net e.g. [android](/questions/tagged/android) logo url is http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-android.png and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) logo url is http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-facebook.png

So who is responsible for those icons? Has Mozilla foundation itself decided to change the logo?

Comment: The Android thing isn't always hosted on the CDN. If you look at [Nicks answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204003/179419) http://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png is the Android logo and that's hosted on imgur.

Comment: @ben sorry didn't find anything related in that answer by Nick... anyway it's not relevant, it was moved there temporarily [by Geoff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153429/152859) and don't think it's in use.

Comment: I was responding solely to your oddity; I'm saying that it's not always true... some sponsored tag icons _are_ hosted on imgur, for the homepage at least.

Comment: You guys are only seeing half the story, somewhere on the Mozilla site  is bubbles, FIND BUBBLES! FREE BUBBLES! **BRING BUBBLES HOME!**

Comment: I wish I was good at Photoshop. I would put Waldo's hat on top of the fox.

Comment: @AndrewBarber [Challenge accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DBEwd.png). Ok, it is super low res, and with Paint, but still.

Comment: @Dukeling hehe... awesome! Though I would have put the hat on the entire logo, not just the fox ;)

Comment: Looks like someone is going to make a hat outta fox's fur.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The short answer is: this is the logo Mozilla sent us in their package of materials for their tag sponsorships (note this logo is also used on [firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os) and [html5-apps](/questions/tagged/html5-apps)).

To get to the bottom of where this logo comes from, just take a look at the logo for the Mozilla Foundation:
[image: mozilla-foundation-logo]

If you still don't see it, black out the dino head...

[image: mozilla-foundation-logo-DARK]

...and from there, I hope you can see where this logo comes from:
[image: tag-spons-logo]

I can't speak to exactly *why* the logo above is being used, but I can assure you **it was sent directly from Mozilla to the Ad Sales team here at SE.**

Regarding the use of cdn.sstatic.net versus imgur:

We used to use the former for hosting those logos for tag spsonsorships, now we use the latter. Note that the examples you cite, [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) are sponsorships that have been around for a long time. Take a look at a more recent (though not that recent) example in [azure](/questions/tagged/azure): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoON.jpg

I hope that clears everything up! :)

---

Update:

In the comment thread of an [article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/11/launching-developer-forums-on-stack-overflow/) posted [on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6764804), Robert Nyman (Technical Evangelist for Mozilla) [said the following](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6765276):

> Yes, I do. :-) That logo is the new logo for MDN, our network for developers at Mozilla. Since Stack Overflow is a resource for developers we see a direct connection to that. Also, we have different foxes for different products, so that would probably be confusing - rather have one consistent look.

Comment: Can I get some freehand circles to show what you're talking about with the logo?

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! Think I found another bug now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoON.jpg won't load for me while http://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoON.jpg works fine.

Comment: And make sure those freehand circles are red, or else.

Comment: I feel like I'm going to kick myself when I figure this one out...

Comment: BTW the short answer is: "Mozilla themselves stole the fox and replaced it with a dino". :-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber can't you see the similarity between the images?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can. I just don't know what that last logo is! heh

Comment: @AndrewBarber think it's just a blue theme to the old logo, no special meaning.

Comment: Someone should poke Mozilla that the firefox logo fits much better, especially when used in such a small size.

Comment: Cool, their plan finally revealed! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the logo for the Mozilla Developer Network, not the Firefox logo: 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)