# Spam mask for deleted answers doesn't work on mobile version of site

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, mobile-web, spam

The [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/182513) that masks Spam/Offensive answers for 10K users doesn't appear to work on the mobile version of the site.

I was looking at [Who stole the fox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204433/182513) on my phone when I saw the deleted answer in its entirety.

[image: Image of Unmasked SPAM Answer from Mobile site]

But when I later looked at the post from my desktop, I saw the masked version.

[image: Image of Masked SPAM Answer from full site]

Is the Spam mask not enabled on the mobile version of the site, or is it supposed to be enabled and just not working?

Comment: That's an oversight. I never remember the mobile version :(

Comment: @Oded too bad there isn't a [meta-tag:status-oversight] tag.

Comment: @Oded I thought the mobile theme is only bunch of different JS/CSS files... guess I was wrong!

Comment: @psubsee2003 You have more than enough rep to create a new tag ;)

Comment: @Servy but it won't be the fun red color of the other status badges

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - naw. We have a few mobile views as well.

Comment: @Oded oh the redundancy... ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My bad.

I hardly ever use the mobile version and keep forgetting the mobile views :(

Fixed in the next build (rev 2013.11.6.1133)