# Spam and rude/abusive questions aren't hidden behind revision history link on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, spam, offensive

I just reached 10k on SO yesterday. Today, when I was going to inspect a spam question, I saw this:

[image: wrong]

I expected that it should be hidden, presenting me with a link to the revision history, but it wasn't. I'm not a diamond mod, so that's too explicit to show me the content directly.

I switched to desktop view, and saw the question hidden as expected:

[image: right 1]

However, spam and rude/abusive *answers* are properly hidden on mobile web:

[image: right 2]

Related: [Spam mask for deleted answers doesn't work on mobile version of site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204442/350567)

This well indicates that a similar issue occurred when masking was first done for answers. Masking for questions wasn't implemented on the full site until later, so it appears to be a very similar case. Also, it's [the only other result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web+spam) if you search for `[mobile-web] [spam]`.

Comment: Well, for answers it was [reported and fixed few years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204442/spam-mask-for-deleted-answers-doesnt-work-on-mobile-version-of-site). Probably the developer didn't touch questions, or the mask for questions was added only at some later point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup. That one's [the **only** result](/questions/tagged/mobile-web+spam) for search `[spam] [mobile-web]`.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238900/when-hiding-contents-of-spam-answer-also-hide-or-delete-the-comments (though not only mobile, comments are just not hidden)

Comment: Found the reason why Oded didn't apply this for questions too. As [this proves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213201/obscure-the-title-and-text-when-question-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offen), by the time he fixed it for answers, spam questions were not masked at all, even in full site theme. This was added only years later for some odd reason, and whoever added it didn't apply it to mobile theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done now; as surmised in the comments, the previous behavior was a bit of a patchwork; now it should be consistently applied across questions and answers for both the mobile and desktop themes.

[image: screenshot of mobile theme with question title and body obscured]