# 'help' link is located lower than the other items

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

It shows like this on Firefox 25 and Internet Explorer 11 (minus the red line of course):

[image: screenshot]

Chrome seems to be fine.

Comment: Thats horrible (it's much more obvious if you have the review link which isn't affected and is right next to the help link), I think it's new, I'd notice a thing like that

Comment: yep, noticed that too. Shouldn't the new top bar be a departure from text links anyway? How about a nice question mark.

Comment: Maybe after [someone stole the fox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204433/) the browser feels down... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this is going out over the next few minutes - browser inconsistency happening there.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it!

```
.topbar .icon-help .triangle {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: And when are you deploying? :)

Comment: @hims056 As soon as I get around to sending in a resume. :)

Comment: @hims056 Six to eight weeks, duh... :-)